# generate a new column by adding a value to spark dtaframe column

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

i have column in spark dataframe which has integer. how to generate a new column by adding one to each value in column using Spark Java

Answer (score 2):

You can use df.withColumn to add the new column to the Dataframe.

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
DataFrame df2 = df1.withColumn("new_column", col("column_name").plus(1));
```

Comment: Thanks, that's new function I learnt today.